# Swagger returns Unauthorized only through Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger

I wanted to add the possibility to add headers directly through Swagger but only on certain actions and I found simply adding Header parameters was the simplest solution.

For my authorization I am using JWT tokens and note everything works in my browser & postman

Here's my action

[Authorize(Policy = "RequireAuth")]
[HttpGet("get")]
public IActionResult GetAction([FromHeader(Name="Authorization")][Required] string requiredHeader)
{
return Ok(requiredHeader);
}

but when I add - Bearer ACTUALJWTTOKEN - it still returns unauthorized.

Am i misunderstanding the usage of adding header parameters to Swagger, shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can configure swagger to use Auth

in your Startup class
put this code in ConfigureServices method

```
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
                c.SchemaGeneratorOptions.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings = true;
                c.SchemaGeneratorOptions.DescribeStringEnumsInCamelCase = true;
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "My API", Version = "v1"});
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer",
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                        Description =
                            "Please enter into field the word 'Bearer' following by space and JWT",
                        Name = "authorization",
                        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                    });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement() {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                            Reference =
                                new OpenApiReference {
                                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Bearer"
                                },
                            Scheme = "oauth2",
                            Name = "Bearer",
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                    }
                });
                c.SchemaFilter<EnumSchemaFilter>();
            });
```

Comment: But as far as I understand then every call would have the header included? I don't want to throw an authorization header towards my registering action and several others

Comment: you can use [AllowAnonymous] attribute for them

Comment: I've completely forgotten about that one. Thanks, I will try it out tomorrow